# Do you only post high scores to the facebook scores api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Should I post all scores from my game to the facebook scores api or just when they get a new high score?

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing you'd just send the new high score over to Facebook's API. That way you're only sending the data that's needed not sending any unnecessary data.

Comment: The askee can guess... he wants to know.